# Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'. What is this & how to solve it?

Tags: android, build.gradle

When I tried to run the project, it showed this error.

**The names are all valid but still this error is irritating me**!

***Here is the error:***

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/hammadnasir/AndroidstudioProjects/DuaThePowerfulWeapon/res/drawable-hdpi/dua_when_leaving_mosque.JPG: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])
```

***Here is my build.gradle file:***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

**I tried and searched a lot about this, but still I am unable to resolve this ERROR!!!**

**Kindly help me!**

**All help will be highly appreciated.**

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates:

.../res/drawable-hdpi/dua_when_leaving_mosque.JPG: Error: **Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters** and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

The file name indicated has upper-case letters (**.JPG**).

Rename the file from `dua_when_leaving_mosque.JPG` to `dua_when_leaving_mosque.jpg`